# R forestplot package blank lines with section headings

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I want to generate a forest plot using the forestplot package in R that looks like the following image

[image: Example forest plot]

I have several sections I want to join together in a single long plot with a single axis at the bottom, but with the section headings separating each one. I can generate each forestplot independently and put them together, but the elements do not line up.

How do I generate the plot like this?